# how to convert hexcode color into uicolor (svg image)

Tags: ios, xcode, image, svg, uicolor

I am using svg image for my program .at first I need to draw the outline of the image using its coordinates and then the real colors i.r the colors in original image should appear. I have used some code to change the hex code into `UIColor` but its n0t working for every image .

plz suggest me some code that can be used for evry image hopefully !!

this is the code I used

```
-(UIColor *)colorWithHexString {

/* convert the string into a int */
unsigned int colorValueR,colorValueG,colorValueB,colorValueA;
UIColor *color;
NSString *hexStringCleared = [[[PocketSVG sharedManager]colorstr] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
if(hexStringCleared.length == 3) {
    /* short color form */

    hexStringCleared = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)],[hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)],
                        [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)],[hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)],
                        [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)],[hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)]];
}
if(hexStringCleared.length == 6) {
    hexStringCleared = [hexStringCleared stringByAppendingString:@"ff"];
}

if ([hexStringCleared isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
    color=[UIColor clearColor];
}
if ([hexStringCleared isEqualToString:@"url(#SVGID_1_)"] || [hexStringCleared isEqualToString:@"url(#SVGID_2_)"] ||[hexStringCleared isEqualToString:@"url(#SVGID_3_)"] || [hexStringCleared isEqualToString:@"url(#SVGID_2_)"]) {
    color=[UIColor clearColor];
}


NSString *red = [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
NSString *green = [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
NSString *blue = [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)];
NSString *alpha = [hexStringCleared substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)];

[[NSScanner scannerWithString:red] scanHexInt:&colorValueR];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:green] scanHexInt:&colorValueG];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:blue] scanHexInt:&colorValueB];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:alpha] scanHexInt:&colorValueA];

color=[UIColor colorWithRed:((colorValueR)&0xFF)/255.0
                      green:((colorValueG)&0xFF)/255.0
                       blue:((colorValueB)&0xFF)/255.0
                      alpha:((colorValueA)&0xFF)/255.0];
return color;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .pch file

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Access it like

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x3c57ae)];
```

Comment: not working , can you plz xplain the code , actualy i hav stored the hex code in nsstring type  object .

Comment: consider the color code 3c57ae. 3c is stands for red, 57 for green and  ae for blue

Comment: actualy color code is passed from another function :(

Comment: from where you are getting color ? as you said it is in string form. Can you post some sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in this file: [SVGUtilities.m](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh/blob/master/SVGgh/SVG/SVGUtilities.m) you will find a method written in objective-c:

```
UIColor* UIColorFromSVGColorString (NSString * stringToConvert)
```

This will convert hex and a lot of standard named colors to a UIColor. Written by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to convert from Hex to UIColor.

https://github.com/burhanuddin353/TFTColor